# Using GROUP BY/HAVING clause in a JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

I have two classes with parent/children one-to-many relationship:

parent:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER")
public class CommitmentRegister {

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMMIT_REG_ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="COMMIT_REG_ID")
    private List<CommitmentRegisterDetail> details;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<CommitmentRegisterDetail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<CommitmentRegisterDetail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

and child:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL")
public class CommitmentRegisterDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="COMMIT_REG_ID")
    private CommitmentRegister commitmentRegister;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public CommitmentRegister getCommitmentRegister() {
        return commitmentRegister;
    }

    public void setCommitmentRegister(CommitmentRegister parent) {
        this.commitmentRegister = parent;
    }

}
```

I'd like to query for CRs whose details sum total is over 100. I'm using the following query:

```
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

    sql.append( " SELECT CR " );
    sql.append( " FROM CommitmentRegister CR " );
    sql.append( " LEFT JOIN CommitmentRegisterDetail CRD ON ( CRD.commitmentRegister = CR ) ");
    sql.append( " WHERE CR.id >= 91000 " );

    sql.append( " GROUP BY CR " );

    sql.append( " HAVING SUM( CRD.amount ) > 100 " );

    Query q = em.createQuery( sql.toString() );

    return q.getResultList();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6015] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Invalid query key [amount] in expression.
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=CommitmentRegister jpql=" SELECT CR  FROM CommitmentRegister CR  LEFT JOIN CommitmentRegisterDetail CRD ON ( CRD.commitmentRegister = CR )  WHERE CR.id >= 91000  GROUP BY CR  HAVING SUM( CRD.amount ) > 100 ")
```

The query runs fine without the HAVING line and the right details are assigned to the parent (CR).

Thanks in advance.

Table structure in case it's relevant

```
COMMITMENT_REGISTER
    COMMIT_REG_ID

COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL
    COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID
    COMMIT_REG_ID
    AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess here is that it has to do more with the join than the `HAVING`, since `HAVING` should work per the [EclipseLink docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#HAVING_Clause).

Perhaps try something like this and see how it goes:

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

sql.append( " SELECT CR " );
sql.append( " FROM CommitmentRegisterDetail CRD " );
sql.append( " LEFT JOIN CRD.commitmentRegister CR ");
sql.append( " WHERE CR.id >= 91000 " );
sql.append( " GROUP BY CRD.commitmentRegister " );
sql.append( " HAVING SUM( CRD.amount ) > 100 " );

Query q = em.createQuery( sql.toString() );

return q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I would try that, but I'd get an incomplete result set back since some CRs have no CRDs.

Comment: For kicks I tried flipping the entities and I got the same error. [147, 157] The state field path 'CRD.amount' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: Actually, you were right. I did it wrong on my previous attempt. I flipped the entities in the join and the query runs without error with the HAVING line. I do still have the problem that I don't get the CRs with no details, but at least I'm one step closer.

Comment: The `HAVING(CRD.amount) > 100` condition would already exclude the CR's without details. You could consider adding a `UNION` to `SELECT CR FROM CommitmentRegister CR LEFT JOIN CR.details CRD WHERE CRD IS NULL` to get the additional results

Comment: You are right. But the > $100 criteria is optional. Without it I'd want all CRs without CRDs too. Which I wouldn't get it the base join is CRD. I should have made that clear initially.

Comment: Adding the `UNION` will get you the CRs without CDRs